# Java: Missing return statement for a math quiz?

Tags: java

New to Java. The task is to Create a MathQuiz application that asks the user whether they would like a simple or difficult math quiz and the number of questions they would like to answer. The application then displays the questions, one at a time,prompting the user for the answer and confirming whether or not the answer is correct. The MathQuiz application should include separate methods for the simple and difficult math quiz.The simple() method should display addition problems. The difficult() method should display multiplication problems. Random numbers should be generated for the quiz questions. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathQuiz {


        public static double simple() {
        int randomNumber1 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int randomNumber2 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int randomNumberAdd = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;


            //user input
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print(randomNumber1 + " + " + randomNumber2 + " = ");
                int GuessRandomNumberAdd = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (GuessRandomNumberAdd == randomNumber1 + randomNumber2) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong. The correct answer is " + randomNumberAdd);
            }
        }



       public static double difficult() {
            int randomNumber1 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
            int randomNumber2 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
            int randomNumberMul = randomNumber1 * randomNumber2;
            int correct = 0;

            //user input
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print(randomNumber1 + " * " + randomNumber2 + " = ");
                int GuessRandomNumberMul = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (GuessRandomNumberMul == randomNumber1 * randomNumber2) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong. The correct answer is " + randomNumberMul);
            }
       }




         //user options
          public static void main(String[] args) {
          int choice;
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("There are two levels available:");
          System.out.println("1. Simple");
          System.out.println("2. Difficult");
          System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
          choice = input.nextInt();
          if (choice == 1) {
          simple();       
          } else if (choice == 2) {
          difficult();        
          }
          input.close();
           }
           }
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: In your method `simple()` return type is `double` but you are not returning anything like `return 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static double simple() {}
```

`public` -> It specifies the access level of this function.

`static` -> It means this function is a behavior of your class and not specific to any instance of this class.

`double`  -> It's what your function returns, a double typed value here, as an output at end of execution.

`simple()`-> It's your function name

In both of your functions `simple()` and `difficult()` you are not returning any value as output. So you have to change it to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of `simple()` and `double()` method to `void`, i.e.

`public static void simple()` and

`public static void difficult()`

The return type of these methods is currently `double`, so it is expected to return a `double` value. If they don't return a `double` value, the compiler will give you an error.  So, if you don't plan to return a value in your methods, change the return type to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method `simple()` and `difficult()` return type from `double` to `void` and the error should go away

Answer (score 0):

Removing the return type of **double** from your method's signature and setting it to **void**, the error should go away.

```
public static void simple() {
    // your code
}

public static void difficult() {
    // your code
}
```